# How to set /tmp/ on server for a program that runs in python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, server, tmp

I am having some errors with a command-line tool deeptools bamCompare, I'm working off of an aws server. The files I am trying to process with this tool are quite large so it ends up generating a 'no space left on device error' because my `/tmp/` directory is full... The root directory `/` is mounted on a 16GB device and doesn't have much space left, but there's 1TB on the /data/ directory:

```
$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       16G   16G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  380K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdf        30G   29G  1.2M 100% /software
/dev/xvdg       985G  748G  196G  80% /data
```

I'd like to set a `tmp-dir` under `/data` (`/data/tmp`) that bamCompare will end up using. Deeptools bamCompare is written in python.
I've seen answers for setting the environment variable $TMPDIR, but I didn't have that var? (`echo $TMPDIR` returns nothing) I tried it anyway but it didn't work. Is it possible to have the default `/tmp/` point somewhere else? Let me know if anyone has a solution!!

(deeptools: https://github.com/deeptools/deepTools) version 3.3.1

Note, the server I'm working off of also has multiple versions of python installed and because I'm not the only one using it, I can't remove the other ones.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable?

Comment: `export TMPDIR=/data/tmp`

Comment: do you use `export` in `.bashrc` or directly before running code ? You could check in code `os.environ.get('TMPDIR')` if you get `/data/tmp`

Comment: first you should check in source code if it really use variable `TMPDIR` - or maybe it has hardcoded `/tmp/`

Comment: BTW: in Linux you can create `'soft link' / 'symbolic link'` which is treated as normal directory (or file) but it redirect to other folder (or file) even on other partition, disk - `ln -s /data/tmp /tmp` - but first you would have to remove `/tmp`